# Find intercepts in almost flat lines

Tags: matlab, line, hough-transform

I have a set of lines (image below) which should meet in a number of points. As you can see, now the angular coefficient doesn't vary noticeably, making intercepts hard to find. What transformation do you suggest to use to make things easier (like some kind of Hough transform), or where do you think I should look for inspiration? Thanks!

I'm working in Matlab but I can switch to Python if needed.

[image]

Comment: If you have plotted these lines, you have their equations. Why don't you find the intersection points using linear algebra concepts?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar: each line is the Hough transform of a point, and different sets of lines meet in different regions. So I can't just apply some linear algebra ;-)

Comment: Why not? yopu can describe the line with an ecuation and then solve for intersections, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for houghpeaks function (http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/houghpeaks.html)